# Bokeh: Plot does not get updated based on values from select dropdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I have the following 'df' and I try to plot graphs based on state selected from the dropdown grouped by year.

```
S.No    STATE   YEAR    ColA    ColB
1.        IN    2013    150     200
2.        MA    2013    200     250
3.        IN    2015    300     300
```

Code is as below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dfyears.csv')

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure()
r = p.vbar(x='YEAR', top='colA', width=1,
         source = source)

select_state = Select(title="Option:", value="IN", options= df.STATE.unique().tolist())

def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
    if select_state.value == 'IN':
        newSource = df.groupby(['YEAR','ColA']).sum().to_dict('list')
    if select_state.value == 'MA':
        newSource = df.groupby(['YEAR','ColA']).sum().to_dict('list')
    source.data =  newSource 

select_state.on_change('value', update_plot)
layout = column(row(select_state, width=400), p)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

STATE values are displayed in the dropdown but plot does not get updated accordingly, I get the below error when I try to run app in server.

```
error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1): UnboundLocalError("local variable 'newSource' referenced before assignment",)
```

Comment: You are using same newSource for both `'IN'` and `'MA'` conditions. Change that and check. Also change the `top='ColA'` instead of small c.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has lot of bugs and some parts are not correct.I think you need something like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STATE':['IN','MA','IN','MA','IN'],
                   'YEAR':[2013,2013,2015,2015,2016],
                   'ColA':[150,200,300,350,400],
                   'ColB':[400,550,600,850,900]})

source = ColumnDataSource(df[df['STATE']=='IN'].groupby('YEAR').sum())

p = figure()
r = p.vbar(x='YEAR', top='ColA', width=1,
         source = source)

select_state = Select(title="Option:", value="IN", options= df.STATE.unique().tolist())

def update_plot(attrname, old, new):

    source.data = ColumnDataSource(df[df['STATE']==select_state.value].groupby('YEAR').sum()).data

select_state.on_change('value', update_plot)
layout = column(row(select_state, width=400), p)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```